# Spring Security KeyCloak adapter not redirect to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, keycloak

I'm using Spring Security KeyCloak adapter

I've configured it successfully, so the behavior is like:

- (1) If I go to localhost:8080/xyz (my web server) -> redirect to
  http://auth-server/auth/realms/...
- (2) If I go to localhost:8080/ ->
  NOT redirect to http://auth-server/auth/realms/...

So, how can I achieve the (2) behavior?

This is the Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

/**
 * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
        KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
        KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Override
protected KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler() throws Exception {
    return super.keycloakLogoutHandler();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Adding this '.antMatcher("*/**")....' before autorizeRequests fix redirects problem in my case. SbringBoot 2.0.2,  SpringSecurity 5.0.5 and keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter 4.0.0.Beta2

```
.antMatcher("*/**")
.authorizeRequests()
```

Comment: Are you sure that formatting in your answer isn't broken?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the trick :

```
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/xyz*").hasRole("user") //replace with your role
  .anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer
[Keycloak spring-security Adapter: antMatchers("/**").authenticated() does not start authentication process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657946/keycloak-spring-security-adapter-antmatchers-authenticated-does-not-st)

Simply you need to change the logoutSuccessUrl (default is / with permitAll)

e.g.
.and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loggedout");