# Keycloak spring-security Adapter: antMatchers("/**").authenticated() does not start authentication process

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring-security 5.2 and in the configuration I write the following `http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login*", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/vendors/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();`

The application url is like http://localhost:8080/myApp
The problem is when I call the application url the authentication entry point is not invoked.

Only when I modify the last line to something like .antMatchers("/main*").authenticated(); and then call http://localhost:8080/myApp/main everything works.

I am configuring a Keycloak SSO Server (7.0.1) + using Keycloak Spring Security Adapter. So I was wondering, why the Keycloak Entry point is not invoked in the case .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() and only be called if I wrote something like .antMatchers("/main*").authenticated().

Can anyone explain what is wrong in my original code?

Thanks

Comment: configuring `.antMatchers("/**").authenticated();` will redirect access to `/` to `/login` without any doubt. Refer [Help others reproduce the problem section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spring security config class extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and you call super.configure(http)? If Yes, then you're login page is not /login but /sso/login. And a logout success page is mapped to /. When a logout success page is mapped, Spring will automatically set the security for it to permitAll. Thus, you can try to change the logout success page to another url in order to check if its will fix your problem
Something like

```html
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/vendors/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loggedout");
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I am not using a formLogin, as I am configuring a Keycloak SSO Server + using Keycloak Spring Security Adapter. I was wondering, why the Keycloak Entry point is not invoked in the case .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() and only be called if I wrote something like .antMatchers("/main*").authenticated(). But the fault seems to be in the part .antMatchers("/login*",...).permitAll(). If .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() redirects to /login and my code states that /login have the access permitAll, then it is logical that the authentication entry point is not called

Comment: Your spring security config class extends `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and you call `super.configure(http)`?
If Yes, then you're login page is not /login but /sso/login. And a logout success page is mapped to /. When a logout success page is mapped, Spring will automatically set the security for it to permitAll.
Thus, you can try to change the logout success page to another url in order to check if its will fix your problem

Comment: Thanks, changing the logout success url really fixed the problem