# Spring Boot Keycloak Adapter cannot authorize requests to context url "/"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a simple Spring Boot (2.4.5-SNAPSHOT) web project using `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` (12.0.4) adapter for Keycloak integration. I can secure all the endpoints except the context/base url of the application. The requests coming to this base url are not authenticated. Do I make a mistake in the `configure` method?

`http://localhost:3000/greetings` is secure, redirects to Keycloak login. But `http://localhost:3000` is insecure.

**HelloController.java**

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/greetings")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getGreetings() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello world!");
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getContextGreetings() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello world context!");
    }
}
```

**KeycloakSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
        //.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated());
        // Also tried the commented one, doesn't work either.
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

`application.properties`

```
server.port=3000

keycloak.realm=myrealm
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=my-client
keycloak.credentials.secret=b5c3154c-012b-4ce2-af14-d58505a2a54d
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:12.0.4'
    implementation 'org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:12.0.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason thanks to the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58662500/2208467).

In the `configure` method, `super.configure(http);` is being called. The parent `configure` method makes the logout url insecure which makes sense since it's the redirection page after the logout. In order overcome this issue, the `logoutSuccessUrl` needs to be set to another url.

See the last line of the method from `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(keycloakCsrfRequestMatcher())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter(), SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(keycloakAuthenticatedActionsRequestFilter(), KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
                .logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/"); //permits the path
    }
```